# How can I easily access Views in a Fragment that is inflated on Button Click?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a FrameLayout as my container for the Fragments and I want to replace the inflated Fragment on screen when I press a button there. I am doing this dynamically via `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction`. I know that I have to wait a little bit to access the Views in the first Fragment, so I do it in the activities `onStart`. When I press the button I replace the old Fragment with a new one but now the question is when can I access the new Fragments views? E. g. I have an EditText in the first Fragment and I want to give the text in this EditText to the new Fragment and put it in an EditText there. I am adding the new Fragment via `FragmentTransaction` and then I want to define a new `EditText` and refer the `EditText` from the new Fragment to it. How and when can I do this since the new Fragment is inflated on button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should init and update views of a Fragment on its own. Back to your case, do the following steps.

1. Define an interface to pass data (text in EditText) from first fragment to activity.
2. When pressing on the button on the first fragment, call the callback method with data along to the activity.
3. In the callback method of the activity, create a new instance of the new/second fragment which receives the text as a param.
4. In the new/second fragment, write code to get value which passed from the activity, then set it as EditText content.

Comment: Which callback method do you mean?

Comment: When you define an interface which contains a method (the callback method). The key here is you pass data from first fragment to activity then the activity will forward the data to second fragment.

Comment: Yea I think I know what you mean. When I create a new Fragment via right-click-menu in android studio, google is creating a Fragment class with this interface and I have implemented it for all fragments I am using already but I never found out how to use it

Answer (score 0):

you can Dynamically add fragment , use this [Link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments#dynamically)

you can access to fragment with id or name :

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFragment);
if (fragment instanceof MyFragment)
    fragment.setMyEdittext();
```

so declare method that set Text your edittext in fragment and access this method with above code .

Comment: I am adding the Fragments dynamically. I just need a clean method to access the Views of the new Fragment. When I add the Fragment to the activity and then I want to define an EditText like this ``EditText emailField = findViewById(R.id.sign_up_fragment_email_field);`` but thats not working since the Views in the new Fragment are not inflated yet

Comment: i cant understand , you can insert edittext in fragment xml  and then in onCreateView in fragment define edittext   :  `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false); ` and then `emailField = v.findViewById(R.id.sign_up_fragment_email_field);`

Comment: Yea I can do that in the Fragment Class but not in my activity

Comment: umm , you cant connect directly two fragment together , first you must get text from first fragment with call back interface use this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) , then must pass text to second fragment with above code (in answer)